users should not su to other users once they are in root
We have created netgroup and added users part of it,and gave them login and sudo access for those users.
once they login to the machine switch to root, then they should not switch to any other users it should restrict user to login to other users.
Example:
[root@ashburn587186 ~]# su - sydat
Password:
we tried workaround that adding comment on /etc/pam.d/su file.
===========
#auth            sufficient      pam_rootok.so
=============
This works but it is restricting access for all the users
It should restrict only netgroup users not for local or generic users
Is there any way we can restrict only netgroup users not local users to switch in between....
